Create New Custom Email Header Template in magento2?
How to create a New Custom Email Header Template in magento2 and load it into the emails?
How to create multiple headers.

Working Code

etc/email_templates.xml

<template id="design_custom_email_header_template" label="Custom Header" file="header-custom.html" type="html" module="[VENDOR_MODULE]" area="frontend"/>


etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <design>
            <custom_email>
                <header_template>design_custom_email_header_template</header_template>
            </custom_email>
        </design>
    </default>
</config>


etc/adminhtml/di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template\Header" type="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">design/custom_email/header_template</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>


view/frontend/email/header-custom.html

<!--@subject {{trans "Header"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image URL",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Alt Text",
"var logo_height":"Email Logo Image Height",
"var logo_width":"Email Logo Image Width",
"var template_styles|raw":"Template CSS"
} @-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome To {{var logo_alt}}</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0 auto; /*height: 11.7in;*/ width: 8.3in;">
    <h5>Header</h5>
    <header>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt=""
                        style=" width: 7rem; height: 2rem; "></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </header>

Use the below code to load the custom header in the template
{{template config_path="design/custom_email/header_template"}}



Marketing -> Email Templates -> Add New Template
Load Default Template "Magento_Email:Header"
Edit "Template Content" and save template as "custom_header"
Content -> Design - Configuration
Open "Global" configuration
Transactional Emails -> Header Template: select "custom_header"


Go to
Marketing -> Email Templates -> Add New Template

and load any default templates from drop-down there
Edit "Template Content" and save template as "custom_email_template"

then open the "Global Configuration" inside:
Content -> Design - Configuration

Choose
Transactional Emails -> Header Template: select "custom_email_template"

You are good to go. Please accept kudos as a solution.
